# HTML5 Video Live Stream Oper TV Emulator

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, opera, live-streaming, television

I want to stream live video using HTML5. So far I have tried

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>

  <!-- Chang URLs to wherever Video.js files will be hosted -->
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- video.js must be in the <head> for older IEs to work. -->
  <script src="video.js"></script>

  <!-- Unless using the CDN hosted version, update the URL to the Flash SWF -->
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>


</head>
<body>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://my stream url .m3u8" />
       <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
  </video>

</body>
</html>
```

It is not working in Opera TV Emulator. When I replace the url with some mp4 video file, it works.

How to load video in Opera TV Emulator?

Note: Code above is working only for Safari browser. Not on chrome, firefox etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the Opera TV Emulator does not support m3u8. Or your m3u8 stream requires some DRM that the emulator doesn't have.

Comment: According to http://dev.opera.com/tv/html5-audio-video-in-opera-tv-store-apps/, only AVC and AAC or MP3 codecs in MP4 or MP3 containers.